# Using rules in Posts

Tags: php, post-meta, rewrite-rules

I'm designing a theme for a customer. We have only **one post** for each **TvShow**, And inside that post, We have all the **Seasons** and **Episodes**. (Using `meta_post`).

Now, I have a `ul` for **filtering seasons** and one for **filtering episodes**, Like *Show 1st Season, Episode 3*. But that needs adding rules to posts (I don't want to use **js** for this).

Something like: `www.example.com/tvshow-name/season-3/episode4/`

Apparently we cannot add rule to posts using `add_rewrite_rule` (Believe me, I tried a lot!), And I don't know how can I add something to address of the post like pages.

Something like: `add_rewrite_rules('/([^/]+)/season-([0-9]+)/episode-([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&season=$matches[2]&episode=$matches[3])`

**The problem is**: After going to `www.example.com/tvshow-name/season-3/episode4/`, It redirects back to `www.example.com/tvshow-name/`, And I get no season or episode!

Is this possible, Or I have to create a page and create my single post template on that? (It's very ugly, But last hope)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You need to add the `season` and `episode` query vars to the array of recognized vars. Note the small change to your regex as well-

```
function wpd_add_my_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]+)/season-([0-9]+)/episode-([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&season=$matches[2]&episode=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_my_rule' );

function wpd_add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'season';
    $query_vars[] = 'episode';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_add_query_vars' );
```

You can use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) in the template to fetch the values.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the real problem to my question. I used your solution, But still doesn't work. See "The problem is:" In my question please.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed it was the built in post, I missed that it was a custom post type.

Comment: That was my bad, I didn't know it's important for doing such a thing. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty that I answer my own problem, But for others that maybe have the same issue:

I just had to add **post_type** in my `add_rewrite_rule`

```
 add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([^/]+)/season-([0-9]+)/episode-([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=tvseries&name=$matches[1]&season=$matches[2]&episode=$matches[3]"',
    'top'
);
```